# Should you avoid using the same variable name after existential elimination?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

Existential Elimination (also called Existential Instantiation) says:

$$ \exists x[P(x)] \vdash P(c) \text{ For some c} $$

I was wondering whether it's bad form to use the same variable $x$ to conclude $P(x)$ for some $x$.  I personally find it easier to read when the specific x that it was true for originally is pulled out.  But perhaps there are pitfalls with reusing variable names after applying predicate rules?

Comment: Not very clear... From $\exists x Px$ we can freely assume Pc for a **new** term $c$. The $x$ in $\exists x Px$ is not free; thus we can equivalently write it as $\exists z Pz$